# Copy Zip files with string in name from one directory to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to try build a script to copy across zipped files from one directory to another. 
Currently I have the following code which can copy across unzipped files with the required string `_NLS`but cannot copy zipped files.

```
import shutil
import os

source = r"C:\\directoryA\\"
dest = r"C:\\directoryB\\"

for file in os.listdir(source):
    if '_NLS' in file.lower():

        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)

shutil.copyfile(source + file, dest + file)
```

This then moves the unzipped files but not the zipped.

Thanks for any help,

Luke

Comment: 1. If you do a raw string, do not double your backslashes. 3. Do `os.path.join`, do not manually "sum" paths. 3. What do you mean it cannot copy zipped files? Zip files are files. If the zip file has `_NLS` in the name, it will work. If you mean the contents, then obviously it won't work like that because zip file is a file, not a directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "across zipped files" exactly? From a zipped file to a folder? From a folder to a zipped file? Between two zipped files? All three (and the existing) doing "the right thing" based on whatever the source / destination is? Also there are oddities in your code e.g. you're looking for `NLS` (uppercase) in a lowercased string, that can never work. And the copyfile call is outside the loop so only going to operate on the last item of the iteration.

Comment: That aside, you may want to take a look at `zipfile.Path` (similar to `pathlib.Path` within a zip file) and `shutil.copyfileobj` which works on file-*like* objects and would thus be compatible with zipfile's pseudo-file objects (as returned by `ZipFile.open`).

Comment: Hi all, apologies for the confusion. It has been amended, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score -1):

The main thing going wrong is checking "_NLS" against file.lower(). It will always return lower case letters and will thus be false.

The reason the first copy succeeds is that the copy function is not called in the loop, and thus only called once for the last file in the list. Try the following:

```
import shutil
import os

source = r"source"
dest = r"dest"

if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest)

for file in os.listdir(source):
    if "_NLS" in file:
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
```

Also join your file paths using `os.path.join` to avoid operating system specific errors.